# Xdebug 3 not showing Stack trace on Fatal Error since upgrading

Tags: xdebug

I used to see the full stack V2 when there was a fatal error.  Now I only see the last line.

I read some articles and played around with php.ini but still no luck.
I am using PhpStorm and WAMP on Windows 10.

Comment: Please share more details about your configuration, and your attempts to fix the configuration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that `develop` is part of your `xdebug.mode` settings.

This is the default, but if you change it to `xdebug.mode=debug`, you remove the `develop` part and hence won't see the "nice" orange errors. You can have them both on by using for example: `xdebug.mode=develop,debug`.

Comment: Thanks. It saved me from mental breakdown! :) After Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, debugging with PHPStorm stopped printing call stack. Even official xdebug documentation was not very elaborative.